# Instagram API - Instasharper giving 'challenge_required' error on login

Tags: c#, instagram

I have been using the Instagram API library Instasharper successfully over the last few months to help automate a few Instagram tasks for me.

Using a very similar approach to the below to get logged in.

https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper/blob/develop/InstaSharper.Examples/Program.cs

However about a week ago this has suddenly stopped working, where it is now giving me an error of 'challenge_required'on login.

Has anyone any ideas why this has started to happen?

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you calling `.Result` no a task instead of `await`ing it? You're going to run into problems doing this.

Comment: I think this was just laziness originally (can't remember it was a long while ago I wrong the code), there is no UI it just runs inside an azure function periodically so I didn't need to worry about UI locking etc, but I agree it's bad practice and my wrists should be slapped.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Steps:

1- login instagram in your browser

2-Copy 'www.instagram.com/challenge/' in your address bar

3-Select this was me